# How to not open duplicate links

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my attempted code to open all the pipelines inside of the dashboard

```
function() 
{ 
     jQuery("a[href*='pipelines.cgi?pipelines=']").each(function (index, a) {
     window.open(a.href, '_blank'); }); 
}
)();
```

Here is the HTML

```
  <tr>
    <td width="30px">20150131</td>
    <td width="470px">

        <a href="pipelines.cgi?pipelines=AGS-PART5&dates=20150131">AGS-PART5</a>

            (
        <a title="View jobs upstream of this pipeline" href="pipelines.cgi?pipelines=AGS-PART5&dates=20150131&action=view-upstream">↑</a>
            )
</td>
<td width="15px">
<td>
<td width="280px">
</tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="30px">20150131</td>
        <td width="470px"><a href="pipelines.cgi?pipelines=FBA-MARKETING&dates=20150131">FBA-MARKETING</a>
        (
        <a title="View jobs upstream of this pipeline" href="pipelines.cgi?pipelines=FBA-MARKETING&dates=20150131&action=view-upstream">↑</a>
        )
        </td>
<td width="15px">
<td>
<td width="280px">
</tr>
```

So the problem is I dont want to open the "View jobs upstream of this pipeline", but it contain the same selector

Edit:
Thank you David Hughes for your code. Only one more thing to exclude.

```
    <b> 
<a href="pipelines.cgi?pipelines=FBA-WBR&dates=20150207&action=view-dashboard&arg1=‌​last_week"> See how this Dashboard looked at this time last week</a>
 </b>
```

Comment: If understand correctly what you're trying to achieve; please don't do that... There is pretty much nothing I can think of that's more annoying then a website trying to open up several new windows. People will really hate you for that. And it has been so since 1995, when it was still considered funny by script kiddies...

Comment: The solution is actually pretty simple. Just check with an if-else statement within the `each`. If the link hasn't got a `title` open, else ignore.

Comment: if you still want to do that, you can use jquery `filter` ( `.filter(function(index){return index%2==0})`) in case that you only want to change target in every odd link. Or you can manually add attribute target to those links you want to behave differently.

Comment: @giorgio   Oh. I am not the owner of the website. I am the end-user trying to automate my daily task.

Comment: @Mouser can you please post your suggestion as an answer? I am fairly new to Javascript, so I don't know how to cooperate your suggestion into my code

Comment: @HienLe, I think David Hughes answer is suited nicely for this situation.

Comment: @HienLe That explains things ;) In that case; please do that! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `not()` to filter the selection to ignore links that have a title attribute:

```
function() 
 { 
 jQuery("a[href*='pipelines.cgi?pipelines=']").not("[title]").each(function (index, a) {
 window.open(a.href, '_blank'); }); 
 }
 )();
```

Comment: <b>
<a href="pipelines.cgi?pipelines=FBA-WBR&dates=20150207&action=view-dashboard&arg1=last_week"> See how this Dashboard looked at this time last week</a>
</b>







How do you exclude this too? Your code worked perfectly. Thank you very much